# AJAX completely disabled postback on button click event

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, asp.net-4.0, scriptmanager

I've added a `ScriptManager` and `UpdatePanel` in my user control but now the page is not posting back, at all.  This is the only instance of a `ScriptManager` on the page.  I'm using VS 2010 and my project is compiled with the 4.0 framework.  `EnablePartialRendering` is set to `true` in the `ScriptManager` control.  Could I be missing an assembly reference/registration, somewhere?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" /> 

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="Server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:ImageButton ID="SignUp" runat="server" AlternateText="SignUp"
            class="tips_button" ImageUrl="/~/myimage.ashx"
            onclick="SignUp_Click" ToolTip="Find" /> 
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers> 
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SignUp" EventName="Click" /> 
    </Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `UpdateMode` to `Always` instead of `Conditional`. Also, for something this simple you shouldn't need to specify any triggers. If no triggers are specified, the control assumes that everything should be asynchronous.

I would also check to make sure that required field validators aren't interfering with the postback. To test this, set the `CausesValdiation` property of the `ImageButton` to false.

Comment: Thanks - I went ahead and tried both of your suggestions, but I'm still not getting a postback on the click event.

Comment: Do you have any validators on the page that might be interfering with it? You can test this by setting `CausesValidation` to false.

Comment: I do have required field and regEx validators on the page, but I don't see the "CausesValidation" property any where.  Where is that set?

Comment: `CausesValidation` is a property of the ImageButton.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `Trigger` setup for any controls within an `UpdatePanel` `ContentTemplate`.  By default all controls will postback using ajax and then new content within the `ContentTemplate` will be rendered.

You have a `Trigger` setup for the control that is already inside so that could be what is causing the problem so remove it as it is not necessary.  You use a `Trigger` when you want the `UpdatePanel` to get 'triggered' by a control outside of it's `ContentTemplate`.

Everything else looks ok.  Make sure you have `SignUp_Click` setup in your codebehind and test it by putting a break point on some code in your `Page_Load` which should be hit anytime there is a postback.

Side issue:  The code `ImageUrl="/~/myimage.ashx"` in your `ImageButton` looks a little odd... that extra slash at the beginning might cause some problems.